# why two different Integers could be converted to the same HEX number?

Tags: mysql, hex

I have had to work in a project where we have an identifier in HEX.

Example, `B900001752F10001`, is received in a parser developed in **JAVA** in a SIGNED LONG variable. We store that variable in a SIGNED BIGINT variable in MySQL DB.

Every time we need the HEX Chain we use HEX(code) function and we get what is expected.

But when we have to provision the master table, we need to input valid codes, to achieve that we used something like:

`Update employee set code=0xB900001752F10001 where main_employee_id=1002;`

it worked in the past producing code to be stored in DB as

`13330654997192441857`

but now we are using the same exact instruction and we are getting code stored in DB as

`-5116089076517109759`

So Comparing those two numbers by using HEX function, those provide the same HEX NUMBER.

```
select HEX(-5116089076517109759), HEX(13330654997192441857)
0xB900001752F10001, 0xB900001752F10001
```

Could someone please provide ideas why this is happening? How we should handle this from the provisioning perspective we need to assure storing as `13330654997192441857` so when an authentication event happen codes match.

I have  run without any other idea, I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have overflowed the datatype.

According to [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-overview.html), signed bigint is in the range of

```
-9,223,372,036,854,775,808
```

to

```
9,223,372,036,854,775,807
```

Your number

```
18,446,744,073,709,551,615
```

has exceeded the above positive bound so it overflows and is
interpreted as a negative number.

Having that said, I think you may still be okay with your command -- it is only when you try to interpret the hex pattern as a number the result looks confusing.

```
Update employee set code=0xB900001752F10001 where main_employee_id=1002;
```

Answer (score 0):

64bite machine，top digit is sign bit,so the biggest num is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807,but if ur num more than it,the top digit will transform to be 1,so the num will be negative and its overflowed.
so ur 13330654997192441857 will become to 5116089076517109759.